# how to configure Jenkins reverse proxy 8443 to 443 using nginx server?

Tags: nginx, ssl, jenkins, https, reverse-proxy

I have configured and enabled SSL on my jenkins server, I'm able to access my jenkins server using

> https://jenkins:8443

I want to configure reverse proxy so that I can able access my jenkins server on port 443.

> https://jenkins

I tried following couple of ways like below

https://serverfault.com/questions/828130/how-to-run-nginx-ssl-on-non-standard-port

https://lihaimei.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/nginx-configuration-for-https/

But still redirection is not working. Anyone could suggest me any sample configuration or steps to achieve the same.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to proxy pass nginx config to port 8080 where jenkins applicaiton is running and setup ssl there.
something like this, when using letsencypt ssl:

```
server {
server_name jenkins.domain.com;

location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;
   }

   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
 if ($host = jenkins.domain.com) {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 } # managed by Certbot

 listen 80;
 server_name jenkins.domain.com;
 return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```